# Match all characters except for certain words

Tags: python, regex

I have been learning Regex (while implementing it in python) the past couple days and haven't figured out how to solve this problem.

I have text in this format:

```
FOO1 = BAR2 AND Var1
Gene3 = Gene4 >= 3
Kinase = MATH OR NOT Science
BOOP = 3
```

I would like to identify each variable name (e.g. FOO1, BAR2, BOOP) and ignore any of the logical operators (e.g AND, OR, NOT)

Here is my attempt to a solution: `(?!AND)(?!OR)(?!NOT)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

I am having trouble telling the look-behinds to recognize AND, OR, NOT as words rather than a set of individual characters.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a famouse quote about regex you should look up ...

Comment: what do you want from the string. Do you want to check if foo1 etc.. is in the string or find them in strings that don't contain logical operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks for showing your attempts. Second, let's try to improve your regex in several ways:

1. You've got some nice lookaheads which could be simplified to: `(?!AND|OR|NOT)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`
2. We don't really need a capturing group `(?!AND|OR|NOT)[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
3. Let's add a wordboundary to prevent partial matching `(?!AND|OR|NOT)\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Let's take an example `foo AND bar` as input:

```
foo AND bar
^ Checks if there is no "AND", "OR" or "NOT" literally
since there isn't, it will match foo with [a-zA-Z0-9]+

foo AND bar
   ^ no match

foo AND bar
    ^ Here it will fail because of the negative lookahead

foo AND bar
     ^ It will succeed because there is no "AND", "OR" or "NOT" literally
```

So the solution is to add a wordboundary `\b`, this is the same as `(?<!\w)`. Which means the regex would fail if there is a word character behind.

```
foo AND bar
     ^ fail, because there is a word character behind

foo AND bar
        ^^^ match
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eZ1xR8/1)</kbd>

Comment: Seems we came to a similar conclusion at a similar time. I like your process for walking a user through the problem/solution, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial! It is much appreciated. I can see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a word boundary (`\b`).  This is useful for finding the start or end of a word.  It works by doing a zero-length assertion (so it doesn't actually match anything, kind of like the anchors `^` and `$`) on `(^\w|\w\W|\W\w|\w$)`.  In other words, makes sure there is a word (`\w` === `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) next to a non-word character or the beginning/end of a string.  You can also combine your expression (and the capture group is most likely unnecessary):

```
\b(?!AND|OR|NOT)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/zV5bI7/2)

Note that a word boundary is not needed at the end of the expression, since regex is greedy and will grab as much of `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` as possible.

---

If your variables can have underscores (`_`) in them, it may be cleaner to use the `\w` shorthand character class (which, mentioned above, is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).  The final expression would be:

```
\b(?!AND|OR|NOT)\w+
```

---

Side note: `(?!...)` is a negative look *ahead* not *behind* (they are making sure the characters in front of the engine's internal pointer do not match `...`).

Comment: Yeah, I confused the syntax for look  ahead and look behinds. Thanks for the clarification and the answer.